# if_exists returning false negatives remote url

Tags: php, api, file-exists

I'm currently designing a World of Warcraft Guild Website for a friend using the wowarmoryapi.
however I'm currently doing a members list, and not all members (lower levels etc) have images yet. 
So I figured I would just filter out the ones returning false images and show a "blankportrait.png" in their place.

Here is the code I'm using, (It's on a local site, so no links I'm afraid)

```
            $portrait = $member['character']['thumbnailURL'];
        $noportrait = "wp-content/themes/the-confederation/inc/images/blankportrait.png";
            if (file_exists($portrait)) {
                $portrait;
            } else {
                $portrait = $noportrait;
            };
        ?>
            <div class="member">
            <div class="memberportrait"><img src="<?php echo $portrait ?>"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists` should only be used on local or networked drives. In your case, you want to see if the string exists (or is non-empty). You can do the following:

```
$portrait = $member['character']['thumbnailURL'];
$noportrait = "wp-content/themes/the-confederation/inc/images/blankportrait.png";
if (empty($portrait)) {
  $portrait = $noportrait;
}
```

Also, if you're in wordpress, you may want to set `$noportrait` to include `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.. such as:

```
$noportrait = get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/inc/images/blankportrait.png";
```

Comment: hmmm, looks like it should work, however crashes the page for some reason... 
"Aw Snap, Something went wrong.... etc"
EDIT: Nevermind, solved the crashing, however its still returning the wrong link for negative results :/

Comment: I just noticed I forgot to mention the fact that it does still return a value, its just a 404 page. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

A solution using Curl:

```
$noportrait = get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/inc/images/blankportrait.png";
$h = curl_init($member['character']['thumbnailURL']);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$r = curl_exec($h);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($h, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($http_code == 404)
{
    $portrait = $noportrait;
}
else
{
    $portrait = $member['character']['thumbnailURL'];
}
curl_close($h);
```